# Is it possible to insert into multiple tables on Oracle using PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, oracle

I tried some code to insert into oracle multiple tables. but it doesn't execute.
Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
String sql = "insert all"
                + "into t_stock_purchase values(?,?,?,?)"
                + "into t_stocks values(?,?,?)"
                + "into  t_stock_status(godownname,itemname,receivedfrom,receiveddate,receivedqty,availablebal) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)"
                + "select 1 from dual";

ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
int rowCount = PurchaseTable.getRowCount();

System.out.println("Row Count = "+rowCount);

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
ps.setString(1, partyNameLable);
ps.setString(2, dateLable);
ps.setString(3, (String) PurchaseTable.getValueAt(i, 0));
ps.setInt(4, (int) PurchaseTable.getValueAt(i, 1));
ps.setString(5, "Purchase");
ps.setString(6, (String) PurchaseTable.getValueAt(i, 0));
ps.setInt(7, (int) PurchaseTable.getValueAt(i, 1));
ps.setString(8, "Purchase");
ps.setString(9, (String) PurchaseTable.getValueAt(i, 0));
ps.setString(10, partyNameLable);
ps.setString(11, dateLable);
ps.setInt(12, (int) PurchaseTable.getValueAt(i, 1));
ps.setInt(13, (int) PurchaseTable.getValueAt(i, 1));
ps.execute();
}
```

Is it right way?, if there is any possibles please provide me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: doesn't execute mean, Facing any error?

Comment: It doesn't show any errors, at the same time records are not inserted into the database.

Comment: is it reaching for loop?, i.e make sure rowCount value is greater than zero.

Comment: ya it reaches the for loop, it prints the row count as 3 (because i have 3 row on JTable). it doesn't shows any error.

Comment: query syntax is wrong, you are missing column name for first two tables

Comment: Itt is impossible to believe that you don't get an SQL syntax error exception with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building your SQL statement by concatenating strings, but you aren't leaving spaces between the clauses; so you end up with `insert allinto t_stoc...` which isn't valid. You also have a duplicated `into` in the second clause.

You said you aren't getting any errors, so you may be suppressing them later in the code. You should really investigate why you aren't seeing any exception as the statement is not valid.

Add a space at the start of each added string, at least where it is necessary for the syntax to be valid:

```
String sql = "insert all"
            + " into t_stock_purchase values(?,?,?,?)"
            + " into t_stocks values(?,?,?)"
            + " into t_stock_status(godownname,itemname,receivedfrom,"
            + "receiveddate,receivedqty,availablebal) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)"
            + " select 1 from dual";
```

... or at the end of each string if you prefer.

It's also better practice to specify the column names for all of the inserts, even if you are inserting values into every column - it's clearer, and makes it easier to spot mistakes in ordering.

Comment: can we insert value without specifiying column name?

Comment: @VenkatSri - you can, if you're supplying a value for every column in the right order; [it's optional in the syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#i2121694). But it's better to list the column names.

Comment: Thank you very much. i got the result.

Answer (score 0):

May be query syntax is wrong and remove `into` in third line , check the following

```
 String sql = "insert all"
            + " into t_stock_purchase(col1,col2,col3,col4) values(?,?,?,?)"
            + " into t_stocks(col1,col2,col3) values(?,?,?)"
            + " into t_stock_status(godownname,itemname,receivedfrom,receiveddate,receivedqty,availablebal) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)"
            + " select 1 from dual";
```